# Share Links With Friends

Tags: sharing, links

I am looking for a solution to share links-with-tagging with my friends, like [DZone](http://www.dzone.com/) but just with my friends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [SpringPad](http://springpadit.com/), or [delicious](http://delicious.com), could be good candidates.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a webserver or some webspace, you can run [**Scuttle**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/scuttle/) on it, which is like having your own [**Delicious**](http://www.delicious.com/) server.

There is also [**Diigo**](http://www.diigo.com), which offers a few features that Delicious does not have.  I have not tried it out yet, but it looks like it can do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

[Helvetihome](http://helvetihome.com) allows you to save and share links between your friends and others.